# EWS ServiceRequestException when opening Streaming Subscription

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to stream a connection to my companies exchange servers to monitor a mailbox. I followed the EWS documentation to create and then open a StreamingSubscriptionConnection. After calling the Open method my application spins until it throws a ServiceRequestException and timesout. Have I configured anything incorrectly? I can't seem to get this to connect.

Code:

```
static StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        Url = new Uri("https://webmail.company.com/ews/exchange.asmx")
    };

    SetStreamingNotifications(service);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void SetStreamingNotifications(ExchangeService service)
{
    StreamingSubscription subscription;
    service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "email@company.com");
    service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-PreferServerAffinity", "true");

    // Subscribe to streaming notifications in the Inbox. 
    subscription = service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },
            EventType.NewMail,
            EventType.Modified,
            EventType.Deleted,
            EventType.Created,
            EventType.Moved,
            EventType.Copied);

    // Create a streaming connection to the service object, over which events are returned to the client.
    // Keep the streaming connection open for 30 minutes.
    connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(subscription.Service, 30);
    connection.AddSubscription(subscription);
    connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
    connection.OnSubscriptionError += SubscriptionError;
    connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
    try
    {
        //Never get past this block, only throws ServiceRequestException
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch (ServiceRequestException e)
    {
        service.Timeout = 200000;
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Opening the connection took longer than expected: " + (int)Math.Round((DateTime.Now - dt).TotalSeconds) + "s");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opening the connection failed twice: " + ex.Message + " after " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            service.Timeout = 100000;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Opening the connection failed: " + e.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Connection Open:{connection.IsOpen}");
}
```

The EWS Version I am using is V2.2.0 but I have also tried this same code with Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard v1.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to test Streaming subscriptions is to make use of the Test feature in the EWSeditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases .

The code you posted looks okay but you don't specify any credentials or the Mailbox you want to connect to for the Subscription. So its going to try connect to whatever the current credentials are and if that user has a Mailbox etc which is probably where its failing. But if you can get it to work in the EWSEditor you can then compare what's happening in the ewseditor to what happening with your code using something like fiddler to look at request etc.

Comment: I removed the credentials just to post the code snippet. It appears to be an issue with my companies firewall that is preventing my connection. This article helped - https://www.gfi.com/support/products/how-to-obtain-the-exchange-web-services-ews-url. Switched to using the internal url and was able to stream. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a authorization problem after switching to oAuth / Application.
I have a windows service monitoring the inbox for newmail with streamingnotifications. The first mail is processed normal.

When an email arrives after the Reconnect time there is a 401 UnAuthorized Exception.
Problem is also in the EwsEditor[image]